# grouping and constructing message

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have the table as below,

```
group_id    patchid     message
A             1     msg1
A             1     msg1
B             1     msg2
B             2     msg3
C             4     msg4
```

I want to construct one message for each group using plsql procedure and each message to be passed to another procedure called inside the loop, the message should as follows,

```
msg = A,1,msg1
B,1,msg2,2,msg3
C,4,msg4
```

the procedure calling as proc1(msg)
i tried with cursor to select the rows and used for loop but not sure how to wait for the next row and then construct the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option: it

- selects distinct [group_id, patchid, message] combination
- uses `LISTAGG` to group values by `group_id`
- passes such a value to another procedure (I'm just displaying it)

---

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select
  3                    group_id ||', '||
  4                    listagg(patchid ||', '|| message, '; ')
  5                      within group (order by patchid) val
  6                  from (select distinct group_id, patchid, message
  7                        from test
  8                       )
  9                  group by group_id
 10                 )
 11    loop
 12      -- you'd call the procedure here, passing cur_r.val to it
 13      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.val);
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /
A, 1, msg1
B, 1, msg2; 2, msg3
C, 4, msg4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I want to include a string before and after patchid and message. Is it possible with Listagg?

Comment: Sure, just concatenate it to PATCHID.

Comment: i also want to concatenate string before patchid and before and after message

Comment: OK. What is stopping you?

Comment: thanks buddy, just want to confirm if it is possible, will try and let you know.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd probably edit the answer and post an example if YOU posted what you'd want to get as a result. My current code does what you initially asked.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.